# node-webcrypto-ossl, GLIBC_2.32 not found, Manjaro OS

Tags: node.js, glibc, archlinux, manjaro

When I try to run an application that uses `node-webcrypto-ossl` node module I get the error:

```
Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found.
```

Obviously `node-webcrypto-ossl` requires an older version of `glibc`.

The version of `glibc` installed on my machine is `2.33-5`. I've tried downgrading my glibc but ended up with a broken system (fixed it already).

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to run my app in docker with host node_modules mounted as a volume. Hence version mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously node-webcrypto-ossl requires an older version of glibc.

No. GLIBC is backwards compatible: applications built against older version continue to run fine on newer GLIBC versions.

Your problem is the opposite: you have an application linked against `GLIBC_2.32` trying to run against an *older* version of GLIBC.

> The version of glibc installed on my machine is 2.33-5

The application is *not using* that version; it's using some other GLIBC.

> The problem was that I was trying to run my app in docker ...

That's one way running against older than expected GLIBC could happen.